# Download file and saving into memory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, download

In textbox, I enter a url and download it to a specific path and to store that download file I have to give specific location and filename of that file before.that is working but problem comes when I download any other format (eg .mp4,.avi) It will store as .mp3

```
NSString * URL =Textbox.text;
dest_path=[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppending:@"/Documents/file.mp3"];
//to download url and save to specific path
download=[Downloader Download:URL withTargetPath:dest_path withDelagate:self];
```

I want that whenever I download It should be save from there format .like If i download .mp4 file .it should be save with .mp4 format.please suggest some code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"/Documents/file.mp3"];



    NSURLRequest *req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:120];

    NSURLConnection *con=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    if(con){
        receivedData = [NSMutableData data] ;
    } else {

    }
```

Use :

```
NSURLConnectionDataDelegate,NSURLConnectionDelegate
```

methods

like :

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)d{}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {}
```